# Read with 8 bits in Rmagick doesn't work correctly?

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I have Rmagick using an ImageMagick compiled for 16bit.

However, I am able to read a file by doing this:

```
file = Magick::Image.read(my_file){self.depth = 8}.first
```

And when doing an inspect of that file, I see that it is

```
PNG 1400x768 1400x768+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 333kb
```

However, when accessing any of the pixels, the values are bigger than 0-255.

Why is that? What am I missing?

I access it like this:

```
red = image.pixel_color(x,y).red
```

I don't understand why the value would be from 0 to 2^16, when I specifically have opened the image with 8 bits of depth.

Comment: Need to see how your accessing the pixels. I'm guessing that the pixel values are not 0-255, but more 0-[QuantumRange](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#Miscellaneous_constants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of ImageMagick you are using is Q16 (16-bit). This means that ImageMagick will always use an unsigned short internally to store a channel of a pixel. You could switch to the Q8 version of ImageMagick if all your images are 8-bit. More info about the architecture of ImageMagick can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php